# Store and forward mail but change FROM header in forwarded mail

Tags: procmail

I need a procmail recipe which stores the mail and forwards it to another address.

The following works fine:

```
:0c
! addressto@forward.to
```

But..now I need to change the `From:` header in the mails that are being forwarded, and I know it can probably be done with formail but I failed to find any good examples on how to do that *and* still store the email

EDIT:
solved it myself, see the answer below

Answer (score 7):

I managed to solve it by using this recipe, and I also added a line that changes the *From:* address for the system where we forward it to

```
# store mail in default folder and continue after that
:0c
${DEFAULT}

# change header
:0fhw
| formail -i "From: fakefromaddress@forothersystem.com"

# forward mail
:0
! addressto@forward.to
```